# Can we use multiple payloads in a single action in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am building a react native app and i want to pass different payloads from my application to my redux store. However the only payload that is getting passed is the one i mention first in my action. Is there anything wrong about the method i am using?

App.js

```
<Button title="ADD" style={{ alignItems: 'right',marginRight:'20'}}  onPress={()=>{this.handleClick(item.Price,item.Title)}} />
```

handleClick function

```
handleClick = (Price,Title)=>{
    this.props.addToCart(Price,Title); 
}
```

action

```
export const addToCart= (Price,Title)=>{
    return{
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: { price: Price, title: Title }
      }
}
```

when i try to console log action.Title in my `case:ADD_TO_CART`  reducer it gives undefined, but action.Price is coming just fine. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

**EDIT**
Reducer code

```
    export const cartItems = (state = initState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
                let addedItem123=action.payload.title
                let priceofitem=action.payload.price
               console.log("Price"+priceofitem);
               console.log("Item"+addedItem123);
               return {
                 ...state
               }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add code of your reducer?

Comment: your'e sending Price and Title in uppercase and using it as action.payload.title in lowercase. It should be action.payload.Title

Comment: My bad i should have clarified i changed the Price and Title to "price:Price" and "title:Title" as per the answer below. But it is still not working.I will make the edits to the post now.

Comment: do check by console.logging your Title in handleClick function. You might be getting undefined from there

Comment: Not really. When i referenced Title before Price i was getting correct Title but undefined Price.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass payload in object.

```
export const addToCart= (Price,Title)=>{
    return{
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: { price: Price, title: Title }
    }
}
```

You can access it in reducer as payload.price and payload.title.

You can also do like this,

```
export const addToCart= (Price,Title)=>{
    return{
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        price: Price,
        title: Title
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but action.payload.title is still coming undefined. However, action.price is coming just fine.